# Dijit Tree onClick event render undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, xpages, treegrid

Using the below JSON String which i use to render a dojo treegrid on my Xpages application:

```
var data=    {identifier: 'name',
 label: 'continent',
items: [
    {"name": "Africa", "field": "continent", "children": "[
            { "name":"Egypt", "field":"country" },
            { "name":"Kenya", "field":"country", "children":"[
                { "name":"Nairobi", "field":"city" },
                { "name":"Mombasa", "field":"city" } ]"
            ]},
            { "name":"Sudan", "field":"country", "children":"[
                { "name":'Khartoum', "field":"city" }]"
            },
        { "name":'Asia', "field":"continent", "children":"[
            { "name":"China", "field":"country" },
            { "name":"India", "field":"country"},
            { "name":"Russia", "field":"country" },
            { "name":"Mongolia", "field":"country" } ]"
        }

     }
]}
```

i try to create an onClick event, every time i clcik on the node i got an alert  *Execute of node undefined*  How do i get the actaull value of item?

```
var store= new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: data});
var model = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({

    store: store,
    query: {field:"continent"},
    labelAttr :"name"
    rootId: 'id',
    rootLabel: 'continent',
    childrenAttrs: ['children']
});

var grid = new dojox.grid.TreeGrid({
    treeModel: model,
    showRoot: true,
    openOnDblClick:true,    
    onClick : function(item, node, evt){    
    var id=store.getValue(item,"name");
    alert("Execute of node " + id)

}

}, 'treeGrid');
grid.startup();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking what `store` is when the onclick event is triggered. Bear in mind the onclick event will be attached as client-side JavaScript to each item. I suspect it will not be running in the context where you write it, but is a discrete function. So it only has access to the variables passed into the function - `item`, `node` and `evt` - and will not have access to variables declared outside the scope of the function, e.g. store.

You may be able to navigate from the `item`or `node` variables to the data store.

Comment: Now am getting item  is not defined

Comment: All I can suggest is debugging the JavaScript, though it's not an area I have much experience in, so I'm not sure what expected behaviour is for whichever element in the tree is being clicked.